# Getting undefined method `authenticated' when trying to redirect from root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, redirect, routes, config

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I want to redirect the user to a different page if they visit the root of the web site and they are already logged in.  So I added this to my config/routes.rb file

```
  authenticated do
    root :to => 'my_objects#index', as: :authenticated
  end
  root 'pages#index'
```

but when I start my Rails server, I get this error

```
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config/routes.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `authenticated' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fc6753ff230> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.7.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:410:in `draw'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.7.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

How can I implement the redirection from the root if a user is logged in?

**Edit:** Here is my complete routes file …

```
  get 'user_my_object_time_matches/create'

  get 'my_objects/index'

  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'pages#index'

  get '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
  get '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'

  resources :sessions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :users do
    collection do
      get 'edit'
    end
  end
  resources :my_objects do
    collection do
      post 'create'
      get 'import'
      get '/index', to: redirect('/my_objects/index')
      get 'search'
      get 'stats'
    end
  end
  resources :user_my_object_time_matches
  resources :countries do
    get :states #-> url.com/countries/:country_id/states/
  end
```

and here is what I updated the pages controller to be …

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to my_objects_path if logged_in?
  end
end
```

but I’m not getting redirected to the right page.  Instead I get redirected to a place that causes a “The action 'show' could not be found for MyObjectsController
” error.  Here is the log

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-09-10 17:42:33 -0500
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 28]]
Redirected to http://myproject.devbox.com:3000/my_objects/create
Completed 302 Found in 12ms (ActiveRecord: 2.8ms)
```

**Edit 2:** Output of rake routes

```
localhost:myproject davea$ rake routes
                       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
user_my_object_time_matches_create GET    /user_my_object_time_matches/create(.:format)   user_my_object_time_matches#create
                  my_objects_index GET    /my_objects/index(.:format)                     my_objects#index
                         root GET    /                                          pages#index
                              GET    /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)         sessions#create
                       logout GET    /logout(.:format)                          sessions#destroy
                              DELETE /logout(.:format)                          sessions#destroy
                     sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                        sessions#create
                      session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                    sessions#destroy
                   edit_users GET    /users/edit(.:format)                      users#edit
                        users GET    /users(.:format)                           users#index
                              POST   /users(.:format)                           users#create
                     new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                       users#new
                    edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                  users#edit
                         user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                       users#show
                              PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                       users#update
                              PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                       users#update
                              DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                       users#destroy
                        my_objects POST   /my_objects/create(.:format)                    my_objects#create
                 import_my_objects GET    /my_objects/import(.:format)                    my_objects#import
                  index_my_objects GET    /my_objects/index(.:format)                     redirect(301, /my_objects/index)
                 search_my_objects GET    /my_objects/search(.:format)                    my_objects#search
                  stats_my_objects GET    /my_objects/stats(.:format)                     my_objects#stats
                              GET    /my_objects(.:format)                           my_objects#index
                              POST   /my_objects(.:format)                           my_objects#create
                     new_my_object GET    /my_objects/new(.:format)                       my_objects#new
                    edit_my_object GET    /my_objects/:id/edit(.:format)                  my_objects#edit
                         my_object GET    /my_objects/:id(.:format)                       my_objects#show
                              PATCH  /my_objects/:id(.:format)                       my_objects#update
                              PUT    /my_objects/:id(.:format)                       my_objects#update
                              DELETE /my_objects/:id(.:format)                       my_objects#destroy
       user_my_object_time_matches GET    /user_my_object_time_matches(.:format)          user_my_object_time_matches#index
                              POST   /user_my_object_time_matches(.:format)          user_my_object_time_matches#create
     new_user_my_object_time_match GET    /user_my_object_time_matches/new(.:format)      user_my_object_time_matches#new
    edit_user_my_object_time_match GET    /user_my_object_time_matches/:id/edit(.:format) user_my_object_time_matches#edit
         user_my_object_time_match GET    /user_my_object_time_matches/:id(.:format)      user_my_object_time_matches#show
                              PATCH  /user_my_object_time_matches/:id(.:format)      user_my_object_time_matches#update
                              PUT    /user_my_object_time_matches/:id(.:format)      user_my_object_time_matches#update
                              DELETE /user_my_object_time_matches/:id(.:format)      user_my_object_time_matches#destroy
               country_states GET    /countries/:country_id/states(.:format)    countries#states
                    countries GET    /countries(.:format)                       countries#index
                              POST   /countries(.:format)                       countries#create
                  new_country GET    /countries/new(.:format)                   countries#new
                 edit_country GET    /countries/:id/edit(.:format)              countries#edit
                      country GET    /countries/:id(.:format)                   countries#show
                              PATCH  /countries/:id(.:format)                   countries#update
                              PUT    /countries/:id(.:format)                   countries#update
                              DELETE /countries/:id(.:format)                   countries#destroy
```

Comment: Could you please also show results of `rake routes`?

Comment: It is added.  Thx

Comment: How about trying `my_objects_index_path` instead of `my_objects_path`.

Comment: Yup that solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the

```
  authenticated do
    root :to => 'my_objects#index', as: :authenticated
  end
```

bit from your routes file. And in your `PagesController`, do:

```
  class Pages < ApplicationController

    def index
      redirect_to my_objects_path if authenticated?
      ... do other stuff as appropriate ...
    end

  end
```

This assumes:

1. You have something like `resources :my_objects` in your `routes.rb` file. I'm not sure if you're showing your whole routes file. If you don't have something like that in there, you'll need to add it.
2. You have a method called `authenticated?`. That's just an example. Put in whatever you actually have.

Comment: I updated my question with the complete routes path.  Ipmlementing yoru suggestion redriects me to a my_objects/create page (that doesn't exist) instead of the "my_objects/index" page, which would be the ideal.